# how to do drag and drop of record from one list view to another kendoUI

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I have different list views,
I want to drag and drop of record from one list view to another.
I have seen a link in  regarding this,
"http://jsfiddle.net/MZxQu/36/"
I have implemented this in list view,with this I am able to drag the list view content,but I am not able to drop it on another list view.

can u help me

Thanks..

Comment: Not sure if it is a typo error but you wrote `grouop` instead of `group`

Answer (score -1):

Use this instead of grid it will be better i guess:

```
http://demos.kendoui.com/web/treeview/dragdrop.html
```

Comment: Thanx for the response,but I want drag and drop in grid only